# How to distinguish the tautological line bundle and the trivial line bundle on $P^n$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How to distinguish the tautological line bundle and the trivial line bundle on $P^n$?

How can I tell that these are not isomorphic as bundles?

Comment: Over which field?

Comment: And as what kind of bundles? Algebraic? Analytic? Topological? (It's a special feature of the case of $\mathbb{P}^n$ that these three classifications coincide, but this isn't true of varieties in general.)

Answer (score 2):

Does the tautological line bundle have a nowhere-zero section $\sigma$? (Consider $\sigma([x]) = f(x)x$ for some continuous function $f\colon S^n\to\Bbb R$.) The same argument will work in the case of $\Bbb CP^n$ if you think a bit.