# Is the tautological line bundle orientable as a vector bundle?

Tags: vector-bundles

**Question**

Let $\gamma$ be the tautological line bundle of the $n$-dimensional real projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$.
Is $\gamma$ is orientable as a vector bundle?

**My guess**

I only consider in case of $n=1$.

Let $n=1$, and consider the **one** dimensional projective space.
let $\nu$ be a normal bundle on the two dimensional sphere $\mathbb{S}^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Then, there is a bundle map $ \nu \to \gamma$. Then the pull back of the cohomology class $u_F$ of $\gamma$ also gives a orientation of the bundle $\nu$. However, the antipodal points of $\mathbb{S}^1$ are sended to the same point of $\mathbb{P}^1$ and thus, such orientation will be given by some same vector in $\mathbb{E}^2$. But it is impossible, because the orientation of antipodal points should be opposite directions. Thus $\gamma$ is not orientable as a vector bundle.

> **Definition of orientation 1**   Each fiber $F$ of $\gamma$ is given an orientation as an vector space and  ,in addition, for each $p \in
> \mathbb{P}^n$ there are a neighborhood $N$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$ centered
>   at $p$ and a local section $s$ of $\gamma$ defined on $N$ such that
>   the value of section $s$ at each $q \in N$ gives the orientation of
>   the fiber at $q$.
>
> **Definition of orientation 2**   For each fiber, there is a generator $u_F \in  H^1(F,F-0,\mathbb{Z})$  such that   for each $q \in
>  \mathbb{P}^n$ there is an element $u \in
>  H^1(\pi^{-1}(N),\pi^{-1}(N)-0,\mathbb{Z})$  whose restriction to $F$
>   is coincides with $u_F$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not orientable since it is not trivial a $1$-dimensional vector bundle is orientable if and only if it is trivial. A way to see this, if $E\rightarrow M$ is a $1$-dimensional orientable vector bundle, there exist coordinate change $(U_i,g_{ij}:U_i\cap U_j\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+^*$ so the bundle has a $\mathbb{R}_+^*$ reduction since this group is contractible, the bundle is trivial.

See also the answer here to see why the tautoligical line bundle is not trivial.

[How to distinguish the tautological line bundle and the trivial line bundle on $P^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1239802/how-to-distinguish-the-tautological-line-bundle-and-the-trivial-line-bundle-on)

Comment: Hi! I see your answers on MSE a lot, thanks for your contributions! Just a heads up (I'm not going to downvote your answer) but your answer is wrong. Your claim that a line bundle is orientable if and only if trivial is also wrong. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1486105/is-the-total-space-of-the-tautological-line-bundle-over-mathbbrpn-a-non?rq=1 which shows that the tautological line bundle over real projective space $ \mathbb{R}P^n $ is orientable if & only if $ n $ is even. Fun fact: tautological bundle of $ \mathbb{R}P^2 $ covers orientable $ \mathbb{R}P^3 \# \mathbb{R}P^3 $!